# popup refresh main div main page

Tags: javascript

I begin in php, ajax, javascript. I try to do a formulaire that when i click on a button, it open a popup windows. This popup windows content a new formulaire and when i submit this new formulaire i want that a div in the parent web page get the result of the popup submitting.
I had the first script : test.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function actualise_div() {
        $(document).ready(function() {$('#div_a_actualiser').load('choix.equipe3.php');});  }
</script>

    <h3>Actualiser un "DIV" avec JQuery </h3>
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" OnClick="actualise_div()" VALUE="Equipe">
    
    <div id="div_a_actualiser" style="background:white; color:blue; width:50px; height:50px; font-size:25px;">
        <?php
        // affichage d'une valeur aléatoire pour voir l'effet d'actualisation
            echo rand(10,100)."<br>";
            //echo "Session Nanou".$_SESSION['nanou'];
        ?>
    </div>
```

That call the choix.equipe3.php :

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "toto";
?>
<script>
window.open('choix.equipe4.php', 'popup','menubar=no, status=no, scrollbars=yes, menubar=no, width=600, height=800')
</script>
```

And then the third script chois.equipe4.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connect2db.inc.php");

@$rattachement=$_GET['rattachement'];

echo "rattachement:".$rattachement."<br>";

if (!empty($_POST['btnSoumettre']))
{ $_SESSION['id_equipe']=$_POST["radiopack"];
  echo "Equipe:".$_SESSION['id_equipe']."<br>"; 
  echo "Toto";
  ?>
  <script>
window.close();
</script>
<?php
}
echo "<form name=\"go\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" method=\"post\" action=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\">";
?>
<label for="packdebian"><input id=packdebian" type="radio" name="radiopack" value="3" required=""> Debian</label><br>
<label for="packubuntu"><input id=packubuntu" type="radio" name="radiopack" value="4" required=""> Ubuntu</label><br>

<input type="submit" name="btnSoumettre" value="Soumettre"><input type="submit" name="btnAnnuler" value="Annuler" formnovalidate>

<?php
echo "</form>";
?>
```

The problem is that when i submit the popup the div in the main page is no actualise.

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

1. update your jQuery to 3.6.0
2. add

   ```
   window.name="myparentpage"
   ```

to the page you want to update

3. use `<form target="myparentpage" ....>` in the popup